# Change image value of inputfile with js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html

i need to change inputfile image value with js or jquery. I tried but i couldn't. You can see my html code, js code that how i read value of inputfile.

```
<input type="file" style="margin:auto" class="form-control form-control-file"
id="uploadImg" name="uploadImg" accept="image/*" required="">

let urlImage = "/path/Image"

$("#uploadImg").val(urlImage); // is it true?
```

When i try like,

```
$("#uploadImg").val()
//"C:\fakepath\wp2429207-evil-morty-wallpapers.png"
```

When i try this, i take this error.

```
 $("#uploadImg").val("C:\fakepath\wp2429207-evil-morty-wallpapers.png")
```

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on
>   'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may
>   only be programmatically set to the empty string.
>       at HTMLInputElement. (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:3606)
>       at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:2715)
>       at r.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2:1003)
>       at r.fn.init.val (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4:3301)
>       at :1:17

Comment: Have you tried `val()` instead of `value()`?

Comment: i tried both of them, val() is working only

Comment: Does the solution with val() work? Or do you need some additional help?

Comment: i need some additional help, still i can not change inputfile value.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear; you can't set the value of the input element to anything other than the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279227/set-file-path-for-input-type-file) other Stackoverflow question, it is generally not possible to modify the default path of a file input due to security reasons. So what you're trying to do is impossible unfortunately.